# jQuery Datatable column not shown after adding a certain column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a data-table js table starts like:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<table id="demo-foo-filtering" class="table table-striped table-bordered 
toggle-circle m-b-0" style="width:100%">

               <colgroup>
                        <col style="width:5%;"/>
                        <col style="width:10%;"/>

                        <col style="width:20%;"/>
                        <col style="width:20%;"/>
                        <col style="width:10%;"/>
                        <col style="width:10%;"/>


                    </colgroup>

                   <thead class="pattern-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>카테고리</th>

                        <th>해시(MD5)</th>
                        <th>파일명</th>
                        <!-- New UI requirement, column name changed.-->
                        <th>분석장비</th> <!-- New UI requirement, column name changed.-->
                        <th>등록일</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
```

JQuery Code is

```
dtTable = $('#demo-foo-filtering').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url:"/secure-log/black-list/list",
                    type:"POST",
                    "data": function (d) {
                        d.perpage = $("#perpage").val();
                        d.search_source = $("#search_source").val();
                        d.search_keyword = $("#search_keyword").val();
                    }
                },
                dataFilter: function(data){
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
                json.recordsTotal = json.total;
                json.recordsFiltered = json.total;
                json.data = json.list;

                return JSON.stringify( json ); // return JSON string
            },
            "initComplete": function(settings, json){
              $('#divTotal').text("총 "+json.recordsFiltered.toLocaleString() + "건");
            },
            error: function(xhr, error, thrown) {
                alert(error);
                error(xhr, error, thrown);
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            fixedHeader: true,
            "scrollY" : "700px",
            serverSide: true,
            pageLength: $("#perpage").val(),
            bLengthChange: false,
            processing: true,
            searching: false,
            sort: false,
            paging: true,
            info: false,
            deferRender: true,
            responsive: true,
            autoWidth : true,
            //select: 'single',
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

            columns: [
                {
                  data:null
                },
                {
                    data : "rule_name",
                    label: "카테고리" //New UI requirement, column name changed.
                },

                {
                    data : "md5",
                    label: "유해파일(MD5)" //New UI requirement, column name changed.
                },
                {
                    data : "mal_file_name",
                    label: "파일명" //New UI requirement, column name changed.
                },
                {
                    data : "description",
                    label: "분석장비"
                },
                {
                    data : "cre_dt",
                    label: "등록일"
                }
            ],
            columnDefs : [
                {
                    targets : 0,

                    render : function (data, type, row, meta) {

                        var btnHtml = "<input type='checkbox' name='dtSelector' value='"+ meta.row + "'/>";

                        return btnHtml;
                    }
                }



            ]




    }
}
```

This code retrieves data from the server and it displays data over the screen well. However, a problem begins if I add one more column to the table. This column contains a large length of string, URL.

As I add it, the last three columns gets `display:none` and the table rows are displayed none, too.
I have been trying a lot of things, such as readjusting width %, make the hidden columns visible in the column defs.

I guess If I could adjust this particular column width, and make the large string  displayed in multiple lines rather than a single line. 
This issue will be resolved. Do you have any idea to solve it?

If you need me to be more specific in the elaboration of a problem, tell me please.

Good table[image]

after I add URL column with large string value
[image]

Comment: Can you post your HTML output?

Comment: Can you show less code? This is too much for any of us to go through. Please trim your code down so that it clearly shows what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out after trimming large URL string variables. 
If you guys have any other ideas how to avoid it.
You are more than welcomed to answer it.